# Notify post author for a new comment on his post?

Tags: comments, author, notifications

I have a "support" post-type(private) where comments are text replies. The member adds a new ticket and the conversation goes with the comments.

Currently, everything is normal, but I want to extend features.

I want to get notify myself with  "mail@site.com" and also notify the post author email. I don't want the WordPress comment notification feature, it sucks. I want the notification on for only "support" post and to the post author and me.

A simple line of text: Hello! a new reply `<a href=post link>Check Here</a>`

Comment: Wp have an hook called save_post you can hook a function for wp mail so whenever a new post is added or updated you can trigger email when certain conditions meet. Similarly, for new comments comment_post

 Is the hook.